# How to update programs compiled from source (from Github)?

Tags: systemd, software-installation, compiling, software-updates

I'm using Debian 12. I recently followed this guide (https://stopanddecrypt.medium.com/running-bitcoin-lightning-nodes-over-the-tor-network-2021-edition-489180297d5#13c5) to install some software, and the guide took me through the steps of downloading all the source code from Github, then compiling it and making an installer, and then finally installing.

But I got so excited following those steps that I didn't stop to ask, how do you ever update software installed in that way e.g. when a new version is released on Github?

Also, I used systemd to start the software automatically as a service, what happens with that? (I specified the path to the executable file of course).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you cloned the Github repository.

So you `git pull` to update your local copy of the repository, and you build whatever it is, again.  And you install it, again.

You're backing up your configuration, of course.